# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'QuerySet'

Tags: django, object

I just start learn django, and i want to ask to solve my problem

here my models.py

```
class LotSell(models.Model):
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
```

at django admin input with value 0,0666 or something

views.py

```
def result(request):
    price_buyer = request.GET['price_buyer']
    temp_price = LotSell.objects.values_list('rate')
    tot_price = price_buyer * temp_price
    data = {
        'tot_price': tot_price,
    }
    return render(request, 'resultsell.html', data)
```

resultsell.html

```
<body>
{{tot_price}}
</body>
```

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'resultsell %}" method="get">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="price_buyer">
<br>
<button type="submit"> Submit</button
</form>
```

in the end, i want to showing to user with the total price by:
rate (input by admin as decimal or percentage) multiply the price_buyer where input by user

Thank you

Comment: There will only be a single `LotSell` record?

Comment: no, but the other field only text and imagefield, i confusing how to querying the decimalfield then multiplying with user input

Comment: Do you want to multiply `price_buyer` to all the `rate` (s) of `LotShell` model?

Comment: @tranha: so what would be the output? There can be multiple such rates...